# ArcGIS colormap is not active?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, colormap

i have a problem in ArcGIS with colormap. It is not active. I follow the steps written here http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-a-color-map-clr-file.htm, but in my case colormap is not active.

How can I make it active?

[image: my symbology properties]

Comment: My raster layer with floating point pixels reproduced this issue. Linked ESRI page says *Only single-band integer raster datasets with...* so your best bet is to convert the layer to integer type.

Comment: Yes, did it yesterday, unfortunately this is the only solution. Thank you!